# Outlook 2010 connection to Access 2016 program not responding

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

We recently upgraded our access 2007 db to 2016, and after the update our outlook function stopped working. The function looks like:

```
Private Function GetZeusConnection() As ADODB.Connection     
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Y:\path\to\database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Set GetZeusConnection = con
```

It seems that outlook can't open Access 2016 with the current library. Does anyone have an idea?

Edit: in the references it says Access 16.0 object library, and we cannot add the 12.0 library manually (even though access 2007 is available on the machine, albeit with a small install screen, which also seems to change the object library in outlook every time it runs)

Edit 2: It does work when 2007 is the version that has been opened last, changing the references to 12.0

Edit 3: We've already tried to change the version number in the string to 16.0, to no success

Comment: your code is valid. Is there any error message? When you debug, on which instruction does it fail or hang?

Comment: There are no error messages displayed, the standard windows "program not responding" messagebox with a loading bar pops up and the screen greys out. Something to be noted is that in the references it says Access 16.0 object library, and we cannot add the 12.0 library manually (even though access 2007 is available on the machine)

Comment: btw, it hangs on the con.open command

Comment: Just to make sure: your VBA Project in outlook still has a reference to `Mircosoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x`, right? You need that to use the `ADODB.Connection` object

Comment: I don'ty have any experience with Access 2016 but reading some [comments on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ba67853-4cf0-4604-bb89-f456982d2b32/visual-basic-connection-to-access-2016-file-accdb-format?forum=vsdebug) you probably have to use `provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0`

Comment: I've already tried that, I changed the code to say 16.0 but the problem still prevails. @ThomasG

Comment: There still is a reference to activex data objects 6.1. @MartinDreher

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to late binding to avoid version problems. Google for "early vs late binding".